# Laravel create route with variable

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-8

I'm trying to pass a variable while routing to the create function in my controller.

```
<a href="{{ route('customercolors.create',$customer->id) }}" title="Add color" class="">Add color</a>
```

CustomerColorController.php

```
    /**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
    return view('customer_color.create');
}
```

I can only solve this by writing my own route but this is not how it should be:

```
<a href="{{ url('customercolor/add',$customer->id) }}" title="Add color" class="px-4 py-2 bg-gray-800 border border-transparent font-semibold text-xs text-white uppercase tracking-widest hover:bg-gray-700 active:bg-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:border-gray-900 focus:ring ring-gray-300 disabled:opacity-25 transition ease-in-out duration-150">Add color</a>
```

Web.php

```
Route::get('/customercolor/add/{customer_id}', function ($customer_id) {
$colors = Color::get();
$customer = Customer::find($customer_id);
return view('customer_color.create', compact('customer', 'colors'));
});
```

How do I achieve this with the specified routes? I'm having the same issue when I try to update obviously.

Comment: Your route does not use the Controller, it uses the closure

Comment: Nor does it have a `->name('customercolors.create')`, so `route('customercolors.create')` will throw an error... If you want to use the `url()` helper, you can, syntax would be `url("customercolor/add/{$customer->id}")`. If you give it a name, then you can likely do `route('customercolors.create', ['customer_id' => $customer->id])`. So there's quite a few issues with your code. Please re-read the documentation on Routes and Parameters: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#route-parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, as mentioned in the comments you have things muddled up. First, you have a controller file that's never used in your route file - `web.php`. Inadvertently, you are using PHP closure to serve your view. Finally, you are using a named route that doesn't exist.

Make the following changes to get things working:

**wep.php**

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facade\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\CustomerColorController; // path to your controller

Route::get('/customercolor/add/{customer}', [CustomerColorController::class, 'create'])->name('customercolors.create');
```

**CustomerColorController.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Customer;
use App\Models\Color;

class CustomerColorController extends Controller
{
    public function create(Customer $customer)
    {
        $colors = Color::all(); // assuming you want all color instances
        return view('customer_color.create')->with(['customer'=>$customer, 'colors'=>$colors]);
    }
}
```

**Including route in Blade template**

```html
<!-- make sure "$customer" is defined on this page -->
<a href="{{ route('customercolors.create', $customer->id) }}" title="" class="">Add Color</a>
```